# Which is more durable. CPU or FAN?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature

i wonder which of the two components (CPU & FAN) is more durable in a Macbook Pro Retina 2015 (13 inch).

I am asking because i am doing a lot of compiling on my machine and it gets very hot (up to 100°C) frequently. The fan seems to kick in a bit late in my opinion. Sometimes i hit the 105°C and then the fan starts blowing at full power.

Now i was thinking of using a manual curve setup for the fan, like 100% power at 95°C.

But then i started asking myself if i would brake the FAN quite fast. Well, thats the point.

**Which one is more durable. Should i live with high temps or high fan speed?**

Comment: As to which is actually more durable, that is an undefined question which is prone to a subjective opinionated answer and is really not the type of question allowed on Ask Different, so don't be surprised if your question is put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Pro can get quite hot and the fan may often spin at high speed and this is considered normal operation. In addition to it's fan it also dispels heat via its unibody aluminum shell. This can make the surface very hot but this is often a good thing as it is moving heat away form the CPU and other components. As long as the ball bearing does not get clogged with dust then it should last a good long time even when running at high speeds. The MacBooks all include temp sensors which will power the MacBook off if it exceeds the heat tolerances.

I think the question is not phrased quite right because as long as the fan does not fail and it keeps the CPU cool, then it will last for many, many years. And as long as the ball bearing doesn't wear out or the blades become unbalanced you will get years of service from your fan. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

MacBook Pro Retina 13", Early 2015, comes with an Intel Core i5 or Core i7 ([5257U](http://ark.intel.com/products/84985/Intel-Core-i5-5257U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz), [5287U](http://ark.intel.com/products/84988/Intel-Core-i5-5287U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_30-GHz), [5557U](http://ark.intel.com/products/84993/Intel-Core-i7-5557U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_40-GHz)) ("Broadwell") Processor and the maximum temperature allowed at the CPU Die is 105° C, per Intel's documentation on these processors. (See TJUNCTION in the links provided.)

So if it's the CPU Die temperature that's reaching 105° C then your Fan should be in running full on to keep the temperature from going over 105° at the CPU Die, otherwise it won't matter which is more durable as the CPU has the potential to be damaged running at temperatures above 105° C at the CPU Die.